# Image hover color overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website wherein there's an image and when hovered, it has a color overlay. But instead of that color overlaying, it becomes white, the background of the website.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<img src="images/about-img-2.jpg" class="img-responsive overlay" alt="about img 2">
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.overlay:hover {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

[It goes from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbko4.png)

[To this when hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrDQ.png)

I'm sorry, I can't embed images I'm not allowed.

Comment: `opacity: 0` is likely to be fading it out completely (and its hard to know what the top/bottom/ etc properties will do without seeing the full css).  Since you are using an alpha in your color, try setting opacity to 1 or not setting it at all

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply, I changed it to 1 and removed it. But it didn't work, the overlay didn't work anymore :(

Comment: @ne1410s is correct. removing the opacity fixes it https://jsfiddle.net/sbb2eksq/

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are hiding the image itself with `opacity: 0`. What you want is to overlay a pseudo element over the image, like this:

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.23;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <span class="overlay">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="about img 2">
  </span>
</div>
```

Changing only the background color of an image won't work when the image is visible. So to have a real overlay, we need to actually create an element that overlays on top of that image.

Comment: What's the difference between this and just removing the 'opacity: 0'?

Comment: OP stated, that he wanted an overlay. Changing the background of an image that is visible won't work, so removing `opacity: 0` would stop the image from fading to white, but has no effect as an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

`opacity: 0;` is making it completely transparent (i.e invisible) - therefore you see the white background of the website. Just erase that from the CSS of the `hover` state (not from the initial CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="about img 2" class="img">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

**CSS (SCSS)**:

```
.img-wrap {
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: white;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition: all .25s;
        &:hover {
            opacity: .5;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="@/images/village.jpg" alt="Galerie">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the 'opacity' according to your project how much blur you want.
Here is a working copy for your example. You can see the hover effect on the text.(about img2)

```css
.overlay:hover {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.2;
transition: .5s ease;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<img src="images/about-img-2.jpg" class="img-responsive overlay" alt="about img 2">
</div>
```